# Autosar DEM_GetEventUdsStatus association to a DEM Event

Tags: autosar

I'm new to Autosar, sorry in advance. If a component is defined to have a client/server r-port which is intended to connect to the DEM as a DEM Event, then Simulink imports the DEM_SetEventStatus function and thus allows the programmer to set the DEM Event. But, how is the SetEventStatus function connected to the DEM Event? Which specific event is referenced from the component definition? It seems the r-port name defined in the component is different from the event name found in the DEM. Similarly, what about the opposite case of DEM_GetEventUdsStatus. How is the resulting simulink function connected to an associated DEM event?

Answer (score 2):

The connection between the RPortPrototype at the software-component and the actual event that is reported or queried is created at integration time by means of so-called PortDefinedArgumentValues. These are part of the C-API that is used to communication with the Dem, but they are not part of the RTE-API (the ServiceInterface in Dem parlance) that is used by the software-component. A typical argument passed as a PortDefinedArgumentValue is the ID of the diagnostic event according to the configuration of the Dem.

This makes the code in the software-component more portable because it is not tied to a specific ID of an event in the Dem. You can find more information about PortDefinedArgument Values in the document TPS Software Component Template. And the difference between the service interface API and the underlying C API is documented in the chapter 8 of the SWS Diagnostic Event Manager.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it is a client-server port.
Dem_SetEventStatus and Dem_GetEventUdsStatus are the servers and your component should have 2 client ports. You should create the port connections with a tool, such as DaVinci Developer.